# Request Forbidden 403 when request made to Square-Connect from localhost

Tags: angularjs, http, payment-gateway, square-connect

I am trying to make a request to 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations' using angularjs, where call is getting failed saying 403 FORBIDDEN.

Here is the code sample :

```
var url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations';
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer sandbox-sq0atb-JJGltCa375qzAyoQbjPgmg',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "X-Testing": "testing"
            }
        };
        $http.get(url, config)
           .then(
               function (response) {
                   console.dir(response);
               },
               function (response) {
                   console.log("failed" + response)
               }
            );
```

I have made a fiddle of the above sample. Any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/dx6tdrha/

Comment: you are running through CORS issue, it has to be handle though server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`? It means that you cannot access the API via front-end Javascript (like AngularJS) You'll need to use a different implementation like Node.js, PHP, etc.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for suggestion. I am implementing in C# .

Comment: Be sure to check out the client library: https://github.com/square/connect-csharp-sdk/tree/release/2.1.0